# Is it possible to make the functional methods available?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

When developing in C#, using functional-like methods such as Where, Select, Aggregate, etc. is really good for many reasons and I use them quite a lot. However, the Silverlight 4.0 Framework for Windows Phone 7.1 does not seem to include those. Is there any way to change that? I guess I can't just change the mscorlib.dll to point to the one from the full .NET framework, or can I?

Comment: The silverlight .NET profile does not have support for these keywords.  Your only other choice is to use a different profile which does if thats an option.

Comment: Are you referencing System.Core.dll? They are there...

Comment: yes I was referencing it; I added the using directive you mentioned below and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: I don't do active WP7 development.

However! Spinning up a vanilla Windows Phone 7.1 project, and using the following, it works fine - both LINQ query-syntax and extension-method syntax work fine:

```
        var foo = from x in arr
                  where x%2 == 0
                  select x*2;
        var bar = foo.Average();
```

The only thing to note is that it is obtaining these methods from System.Core.dll, i.e. (if I browse it in the IDE):

```
// Type: System.Linq.Enumerable
// Assembly: System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
// Assembly location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\System.Core.dll
```

So: just make sure you are referencing the System.Core.dll for Windows Phone 7.1

edit (see comments) : also check you have:

```
using System.Linq;
```

At the top of the file.

Comment: @ctacke nah, a using statement wouldn't help at all. A using *directive* on the other hand would be a great idea!